# how does $wpdb differ to WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I'm going to write a function to return the next/prev post in a specific category. can anyone tell me what the differences would be in using `$wpdb` as opposed to `WP_Query()`; eg `new WP_Query(args)`? what determines which of these should be used?

cheers,
Gregory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `wpdb` class is the interface with the database. `WP_Query` uses `wpdb` to query the database. You should use `WP_Query` when dealing with the native WordPress tables, to integrate your code properly with the WordPress environment. Use `wpdb` directly when you need to access data in your own tables.

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention that `wp_query()` doesn't exist in WP core, so I think almost nobody of us can tell you what is it.

`$wpdb` is object of the [wpdb class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), which provides ability to prepare and run database queries.

> I'm going to write a function to return the next/prev post in a specific category

Use [next_post_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)/[previous_post_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link) functions to do it.

**Updated:** To better understand when you have to use WP_Query read this thread [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

Comment: can't use next_post_link(). they don't allow one to specify a single category, something that most people mentioning these functions tend to ignore... although one could perhaps get all of the terms for the current post and exclude all of them except for the one needed... worth considering. btw, wp_query() is documentated here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: @Gregory pay attention that you made a mistake in your question: you wrote `wp_query()` - it is a function. But `WP_Query` is a class. It's big different.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. still, does anyone know when one should use $wpdb as opposed to WP_Query ? I've done quite a few searches on the 'net but haven't found any answers, at least as far as queries go rather than updates/inserts/deletes.

Comment: @Gregory I have updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

with a background in relational database development, what I needed was a guide to SQL. I finally found one I could relate to allowing me to understand the utility of $wpdb.

it would appear that using $wpdb is preferable to WP_Query if one is familiar with relational database design and SQL, and wants to keep database access as efficient as possible as long as one adheres to the safety precautions regarding data validation/preparation.

I'll play around with the $wpdb class/functions and move forward from there.

Comment: That’s not answer, is it? You should update your _question_ if you want to add further details.